# I don't want to print if there's no result

Tags: python

```
found = False
for i, line in enumerate(file(name, "r")):
        for key in found_dic:
                if key in line.strip():
```

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Comment: You sure you don't have your `found` states backwards... Generally, you start with Found being false and set to true upon finding it.

Comment: I just want this program to show the file name when result are in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i, line in enumerate(file(name, "r")):
    found = True
    for key in found_dic:
        if key in line.strip():
            found_dic[key].append("LINE:"+str(i)+":" + line.strip())
            found = False
```

I believe this code block should be

```
found = False
for i, line in enumerate(file(name, "r")):                
    for key in found_dic:
        if key in line.strip():
            found_dic[key].append("LINE: %s: %s" % (i,line.strip()))
            found = True
```

You have your `found` values inverted, meaning found would only be set to true when there is no found items, and vice versa.

Also, you were setting the found value to some default on each iteration, meaning only the very last one actually matters. That's not quite right and the default value should be set outside of the loop.

Comment: yeah I tried that, but if I fix true and false it doesn't show any result.